# difference between climatology and meteorology only

Tags: meteorology, climatology

Some basic differences are needed for children to understand only. The language should be simple enough so that any age understands for 5 to 99 or maybe 100.

Comment: Taken directly from [What are the differences between Climatology, Meteorology and Atmospheric Science?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/10746/what-are-the-differences-between-climatology-meteorology-and-atmospheric-scienc).Meteorology is the study of the atmosphere, generally in the short term - the time frame is seconds-weeks. Climatology studies the evolution of the atmosphere over long timescales, including how it may be changing - the time frame is months-decades. ...

Comment: ... Meteorology is about weather now, last week & next week. Climatology is about weather typical conditions over a long time.

Comment: I think both are terms that might not be suitable for a five year old. However, one could try to explain the difference between weather and climate. Weather being the state of the atmosphere at a particular location and a particular time (it's sunny in our garden with a temperature of 20°C, supposing your garden is not huge) and climate being the average weather over a long period, usually 30 years, at a particular place OR region (the average annual (or any time frame) temperature in your City/Country is X°C).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between Climatology, Meteorology and Atmospheric Science?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/10746/what-are-the-differences-between-climatology-meteorology-and-atmospheric-scienc)